# Where should Meteor.methods() be defined?

Tags: meteor

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods

I have tried it in publish.js in my server folder.

I am successfully calling Meteor.apply and attempting the server call from the client.  I always get an undefined response.

Comment: I have also tried within the app.js in the client folder (this doesn't seem right).

Comment: Also tried within bootstrap.js in Meteor.startup.  This didn't work either.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Calling `Meteor.methods` on the server is correct.  That will define remote methods that run in the privileged environment and return results to the client.  To return a normal result, just call `return` from your method function with some JSON value.  To signal an error, throw a `Meteor.Error`.

On the client, `Meteor.apply` always returns `undefined`, because the method call is asynchronous.  If you want the return value of the method, the last argument to `apply` should be a callback, which will be passed two arguments: `error` and `result`, in the typical async callback style.

Is your server code actually getting called?  You can check that by updating the DB in the method and seeing if the client's cache gets the new data, or calling `console.log` from inside the method body and looking at the output of the "meteor" process in your terminal.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  I don't understand the statement "Calling Meteor.methods on the server is correct".  I don't know which file to put the Meteor.methods definition in?  Can you tell me precisely where you would put the Meteor.methods call in an app?

Comment: Also, to clarify, the doc for Meteor.apply says that if a callback isn't supplied then the method should be synchronous?  Is this the actual behavior?  (BTW, for my app, I would like the specific Meteor.apply method call to be synchronous.)

Comment: Any `.js` file in the `server` folder is fine.  JavaScript files in that folder just load and run on the server.  They are *not* sent to the client.

Comment: On the client, there is no way to call a method synchronously.  The browser doesn't let you wait for a result over the network.  So `Meteor.call` and `Meteor.apply` return immediately.  If you care about the result, you must provide a callback.

On the *server*, it is possible to call a method synchronously.  (One method calling another, for example.)  That's because we have fibers on the server and we can block your function until the method result is available.

Comment: @debergalis This definitely needs to be explained better in the docs, would you like to do this or shall I write up some samples in a commit and send it in for you to do as you choose?

Comment: Always happy to look at some text.

Answer (score 20):

There are several places I can define my `Meteor.methods()` (with pro's and con's):

1. **On the server only** - when the client calls the method, it'll have to wait for the server to respond before anything changes on the client-side
2. **On the server, and uses a stub on the client** - when the client calls the method, it will execute the stub method on the client-side, which can quickly return a (predicted) response. When the server comes back with the 'actual' response, it will replace the response generated by the stub and update other elements according.
3. **The same method on both client and server** - commonly used for methods dealing with collections, where the method is actually a stub on the client-side, but this stub is the same as the server-side function, and uses the client's cached collections instead of the server's. So it will still appear to update instantly, like the stub, but I guess it's a bit more accurate in its guessing.

Comment: So why would anyone want to use option 2 when they could use option 3?

Comment: @adrianmc Because sometimes you may use secret information in your method that you don't want the client to know.

Comment: @danyll, you should submit a PR to add this text to the [Meteor API docs](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/master/source/api/methods.md)!

Comment: @d4nyll how do you implement 2? Do you just define two different versions in client and server code?

Comment: @aromero Yes precisely. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17510929/3966682, it's still relevant

Answer (score 8):

I've uploaded a short example here, should you need a working example of this: https://gist.github.com/2387816

Comment: Thank you.  Another point that I didn't quite get is that Meteor.methods() should be called within Meteor.startup().  Your example demonstrates this well.

Comment: It's not normally necessary to call `Meteor.methods` inside `Meteor.startup`.  That's a hook for code that you only want called on the server once all your files have been loaded.  Since calling `Meteor.methods` just registers your methods -- but doesn't call them -- there's usually no need to defer it.

Comment: This helped me understand clearly how methods works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I hope some will find use of this addition, and this doesn't cloud the issue that methods are primarily intended to run on the server as *debergalis* has explained.

Using [`Meteor.methods()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods) on the client is useful too. (look for "*stub*" in the [`Meteor.call()`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call) section too...)
This allows the client to (synchronously) simulate the expected effect of the server call.
As mentioned in the docs:

> You use methods all the time, because the database mutators (insert,
>   update, remove) are implemented as methods. (...)

A separate section explaining use of stubs on the client might ease the understanding of methods calls on the server.

Comment: Thank you. That's why Methods are defined in the "collections" folder inside the Telescope Application: https://github.com/SachaG/Telescope/blob/master/collections/posts.js