# Making a JSON API request from meteor server

Tags: json, meteor

I have a Meteor application which I am to get to make a JSON API request from another service on the server.

I tried using the JQuery package and $.getJSON but as the JQuery package doesn't have any effect on the server, I quickly found this doesn't work.

How can I get the server to make a JSON request?

Comment: Should be usable is there anything visible in the debug?

Comment: The meteor docs for the jQuery package say; "The jquery package adds the jQuery library to the client JavaScript bundle. It has no effect on the server". Is that not the case? When I try to use JQuery in server side code I get "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: I apologise sorry I missed the server word.

Answer (score 1):

As you say... it isn't available on the server. You could experiment with changing the jQuery package in the meteor folder though.

In /packages/jquery/package.js change:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('jquery.js', 'client');
});
```

To:

```
Package.on_use(function (api) {
  api.add_files('jquery.js', ['client', 'server']);
});
```

and see if it works on the server side. You have to call the server with your local changed copy of meteor, for me I do this by using `../meteor/meteor`, your path may vary.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I worked around my problem by using the "request" NPM module, However, I've got a new problem which I'll open as a seperate question.

Comment: No problem. Its worth noting, you might want to use: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods if its for requests to another Meteor instance.

This answer might help if you want to use that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10156935/1329611

Comment: I might do that at some point. At the moment I want the server to poll that JSON feed at a regular interval and update the Mongo collection so it gets pushed out to the clients.