# What is a stub method in MeteorJS?

Tags: javascript, meteor

What is a stub method in MeteorJS?

Why does including a database call make it a non-stub? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what a "stub" is in a general software development sense?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you mean the ones referred to in the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com)? The stubs are the ones defined via `Meteor.methods`.

In Meteor these stubs allow you to have latency compensation. This means that when you call one of these stubs with `Meteor.call` it might take some time for the server to reply with the return value of the stub. When you define a stub on the client it allows you to do something on the client side that lets you simulate the latency compensation.

I.e I can have

```
var MyCollection = new Meteor.collection("mycoll")
if(Meteor.isClient) {
    Meteor.methods({
        test:function() {
            console.log(this.isSimulation) //Will be true
            MyCollection.insert({test:true});
        }
    });
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.methods({
        test:function() {
            MyCollection.insert({test:true});
        }
    });
}
```

So documents will be inserted on both the client and the server. The one on the client will be reflected 'instantly' even though the server has not replied with whether it has been inserted or not.

The client side stub allows this to happen *without* having two documents inserted even though insert is run twice.

If the insert fails, the server side one wins, and after the server responds the client side one will be removed automatically.

Answer (score 8):

For the above code you can write this that will be ran on both server and client, use isSimulation to identify on wich side you are if you need to do specific task :

```
var MyCollection = new Meteor.collection("mycoll")
Meteor.methods({
    test:function() {
        console.log(this.isSimulation) //Will be true on client and false on server
        var colItem = {test:true, server: true};
        if (this.isSimulation) {
            colItem.server = false;
        }
        MyCollection.insert(colItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've arrived at this point, but I can't seem to get this code to import to both the client and the server, in order to use the meteor method and its stub. Where would I write this code or where would I import it? Meteor says that code in the server folder is not shared with the client...

Comment: It makes long time since i practice meteor, but previously, all files from server are injected to Node, all from client are injected to the Browser, and all from lib (or anything else not in server/client was injected in both). But with imports, i think that you need to import the required files in server/main.js and client/main.js (or something like this). And the build system will package everything as expected.

Comment: Okay. So I tried that and it was not letting me import the file into client/main.js for some reason, but now that I know that that is the correct route I will troubleshoot that elsewhere. Thank you