# Should I use Meteor method stubs for methods with no database operations?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I know that I can use method stubs to simulate a database operation before it actually happens on server, as @Akshat explained [in this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17510929/3793161)

I wonder if I can and should use stubs to ensure that a user has the right to perform an operation (e.g. display an edit button) when it does not involve any database operation.

Note that I don't want to use alanning:roles package, I would like to understand how it works and if it can be done as follows:

Let's say I want to check for admin rights. Each user document has a `roles` string array field where I store the user global rights, i.e. `user`, `admin`, `superadmin`, etc.

I declare my `Users` collection in a `lib` folder, available to both client and server:

```
let Users = Meteor.users
export default Users
```

I create a method stub to check admin rights on client only (it is in a client folder) :

```
Meteor.methods({ 
  UserIsAdmin = function () {
    console.log(this.isSimulation) //Will be true
    let user = Users.findOne({_id: Meteor.userId()})
    return !!(user && user.roles && user.roles.indexOf('admin') != -1)
  }
});
```

In a server folder, I will create the real method which call an internal server function written just below (note that in this case I could set the `userId` as argument):

```
import Users from '/imports/user/lib/user_collection.js'

Meteor.methods({ 
  UserIsAdmin = function () {
    console.log(this.isSimulation) //Will be false
    return Users.isAdmin()
  }
});

Users.isAdmin = function (userId=Meteor.userId()) {
  var user = Users.findOne({_id: userId})
  return !!(user && user.roles && user.roles.indexOf('admin') != -1)
};
```

Now let's say I have an edit button on my UI, and I display it depending on the result of the `UserIsAdmin` method. Here are the questions:

1. If the user manages somehow to change the role array or mess with the method, I assume that the button will be displayed until the server answers the method call, right? But it would not help in terms of latency, the UI being loaded anyway.
2. Same case (user isn't admin but modified locally his `role` array), but we check the method before loading a route: the route and its UI will be loaded, right? No rollback? Of course, the UI will not be populated since the publication won't return anything.
3. I deny every insert/update/remove from the allow/deny rules so I could consider that the user cannot modify his own document. If so, is it worth spending time to write method stubs for methods who are not doing any database operation? I mean, it is not a reliable way to protect UI (see question 2 above) and data will not be published anyway. Is there a case, except db operations, where it makes sense to write method stubs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code depends on the return value of your Meteor method, but you have a client-side and a server-side return value. Luckily, it's well defined which one you'll get:

- If you have a callback in your `Meteor.call()`, then the `call` function returns nothing, and the callback function will be called with the **server-side** return value.
- If you don't have a callback in your `Meteor.call()`, then you'll get the **client-side** return value synchronously.

Either way, you'll only see one of the return values. It's not like subscriptions, where the value will be somehow synchronized later. See the docs here: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_call

And to answer your questions:

1. Depends on whether you use a callback. If not, then the admin UI appears, and will not be rolled back.
2. Same as 1.
3. You should always assume that the user is **able and willing** to tinker with all client-side data. Deny rules won't change that at all, they would only stop the propagation of those changes to the server.

Aside of db operations, there's a variety of things you can do with server-side method calls, like accessing a 3rd party REST API using a secret key, starting background operations, etc.

The way `alanning:roles` package works is that it has a `roles` collection kept in sync via a subscription. Their `Roles.userIsInRole` function is not a Meteor method, but a simple function call that queries this collection.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this really buys you much in terms of extra security. You're already hiding the admin UI based on admin rights and then you're preventing any admin operations by a *fake* admin on the server side. Presumably you're also not publishing admin data to non-admins.

Even if you make it really hard for the user to *view* an admin screen they can still see the source that creates it as well as the methods that it calls. They can ultimately reverse engineer what your admin system controls.

It's just really possible to completely hide your admin UI if it is bundled and served up to non-admin users. A common pattern is to create a second admin application on a separate host or port which can only be accessed by admins. The admin app connects to the same mongo db and can therefore control what users of the consumer app can do.

Some of the biggest clues you are giving an attacker are in the role names you use (admin, superadmin). It's just too easy to search the published meteor code for "admin" and get clues as to where interesting things are happening. Method names are also easy to pick out because they don't get minified and obfuscated, choose those carefully.