# MeteorJS Meteor Methods call from server to server

Tags: meteor

I understand that Meteor methods let you do a client to server call, but what's the best approach to call another function or method from a Meteor method, i.e. a server to server call.

Right now if I do a regular JS function call it only works if the JS file is in the lib folder. But I need it to be in the server folder.

Here is the code

I have a topics collection which sits in the collection folder and has the following

I have the following which is a collection

```
Meteor.methods({
    topicPost: function(topicAttributes) {
        var user = Meteor.user(),
            topicWithSameTitle = Topics.findOne({title: topicAttributes.title});

        // ensure the user is logged in
        if (!user)
            throw new Meteor.Error(401, "You need to login to add a new topic");

        Meteor.call('checkUser');
}
});
```

I then have the following method which sits in the server folder

```
Meteor.methods({
    checkUser: function () {
        alert('aaaa');
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem correct. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10156935/223225. Can you post your code?

Comment: Never mind it works no have no idea way, maybe I was making a syntax error working late last night

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *works*, but it's not a great solution. My method for handling this is to have *all* of my functions *outside* the `Meteor.methods`, and simply relay to the proper functions when necessary.

```
// Client
Meteor.call('foo');
```

And:

```
// Server
Meteor.methods({
    foo: function() {
        foo();
    }
});

foo = function() {
    foo = bar;
};
```

The advantage is that the `foo` fn can be called from anywhere on the server without a `Meteor.call`. Meanwhile, `Meteor.methods` only exposes what is absolutely necessary to the client.

**[EDIT]** There *is* some ambiguity as to which 'foo' you're talking about; obviously the server knows you mean the one outside the `methods` call. But if you're feeling confused, you can always rename one or the other. The advantage to this is that there is minimal refactoring involved.

Comment: This seems to be working just fine, not sure what the issue was.

Comment: this is actually a really great idea never thought about doing it this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify for readers who don't notice that the OP's code actually contains the answer, you just do

```
Meteor.call('checkUser');
```

on the server. Per the meteor docs (https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call), on the server, if you use Meteor.call() without a callback argument, the call runs synchronously and waits for the result. For example, if 'checkUser' was written to provide a userId value, you'd just do

```
let userId = Meteor.call('checkUser');
```

On the client, though, you have to provide a callback function as an argument to Meteor.call(), and the userId would be provided asynchronously to your callback function.